# How do I select the maven url in gradle publish task based on build variant?

Tags: maven, android-gradle-plugin, publish

I'm working on an Android app where various modules need to exist in different git repos.  Each git repo will publish its AAR files to a maven repo.  Then the other git repos will pull the AAR files from the maven repo.

But, I need to modify the setup based on build variant.  I need to select the maven URL based on the build variant.

So, if I run:
`./gradlew publishVariant1` then I will get `https://my.maven-repo.website/type1`.

But, if I run `./gradlew publishVariant2` then I will get `https://my.maven-repo.website/type2`

If I need to use a command line like `./gradlew publish -PsomeBuildVariantProp=variant1` I'm fine with that.  I'm just at a loss of how to set it all up.  I've tried using `android.libraryVariants.all { variant -> ... repositories { maven { if (variantName.equals("variant1") { url "..." } else if (variantName.equals("variant2") { url "..." } } }` in my publication block to pick the URL.  But, when I print the URL in each case, I see all the possible URLs printed.

So, how can I setup my publish task(s) to select the maven URL by build variant?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I figured it out.  I did `./gradlew -PbuildVariant=variant1 publish` and then did `buildVariant = property.findProperty("buildVariant") ?: "variant1"` in my publish task and used that value to select a URL.